# Is it possible to enable the title field for the module views slideshow?

Tags: views, 7, media

I'm working with the module views slideshow and was just curious if anyone knew how to enable to title field for the images you upload for it. The alt text field is enabled but not the title field.

And no you don't just go to edit the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The options to add alt and title fields are in the field collections module and not in the field that the field module creates. So look in the field collections module if you have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at [Views Slide show Content title and description modification](https://www.drupal.org/node/1918548#comment-7082432), which details the steps to do this, such as:

- Set the title field to "exclude from display".
- Check the option "Rewrite the output of this field".
- Put the token in a DIV, and style with CSS as needed.